# The slide rule in the science fiction

Tags: hard-sci-fi, science

Inspired by this cover of

[image: Astounding Sience Fiction]

(a particular case of the more general phenomenon of ["Futuristic" Worlds Where Everybody Uses Obsolete Technology](https://io9.gizmodo.com/12-futuristic-worlds-where-everybody-uses-obsolete-te-1646690502)) I will ask:

How popular is the slide rule in the science fiction?

Edit: OK, the question is too broad. Maybe is even the wrong question. I was thinking in *concrete examples* of slide rules appearing in the science fiction, like in my answer.

Comment: "How popular?" isn't quantifiable. It needs to be a questions that has a clear answer that can be validated, such as "what is the earliest example of a slide rule in sci-fi".

Comment: More interestingly the question could be what is the "latest" example of a slide rule in sci-fi.

Slide Rules are ubiquitous in Sci-Fi written before (or set before) the invention of the computer, because that was the cutting edge of calculation.

Comment: Martín, your question is still off-topic here because it's an open-ended list question. Think about this: this site is for Q&A where there is a "correct" answer you can tick. If two people post two different answers listing valid examples of the slide rule, how would you choose which answer to accept? The longest answer? The answer which has examples you like the most? You can't choose an answer, which is why this sort of question -- while interesting! -- is unsuitable for this website.

Comment: @AndresF. I never understood this objection. "People will post different answers, how will you choose which one to accept?" SO WHAT? On other sites they ask, how can I solve this equation, prove this theorem, solve this programming problem, remove this stain, etc. It is EXPECTED that multiple different methods and proofs will be proposed, and this is not considered a problem. Somehow the askers choose which answer to accept if they bother to accept one.How they decide which answer "helped the most" is the askers' problem, nobody else's.

Comment: @user14111 By definition, there's no way to choose which answer "helped the most" for open-ended list questions, unlike with "remove this stain" / "help me solve this problem". While it may be true that there may be not one single best way of removing a stain, the possibility that there is one is not automatically ruled out by the type of question ("product X is the best way to remove stains, problem solved!"). With open-ended list questions, *by definition* there is no way to pick a "best" answer. Ultimately they are not good questions for this website.

Comment: @user14111 Keep in mind each stackexchange site has its own consensus and set of rules; you cannot use guidelines from one website to ask questions in another (see for comparison the standards in skeptics.SE). Open-ended lists questions are off-topic here but might not be in stackoverflow.SE, for example.

Comment: So the question should have been, why use slide rules at all in SF. Then the answer could have been simply, batteries.

Answer (score 2):

Example from the question link: Heinlein. Quotes from *Have Space Suit—Will Travel*:

> Dad says that anyone who can't use a slide rule is a cultural illiterate and should not be allowed to vote. Mine is a beauty—a K&E 20" Log-log Duplex Decitrig. Dad surprised me with it after I mastered a ten-inch polyphase.

> I tell you, the slide rule is the greatest invention since girls.

And (I *suppose* by the title): *Trio for Slide Rule and Typewriter* by Hal Clement.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The question is asking for it’s popularity, you’ve only stated an example.

Comment: Please do not elaborate or clarify the question *in an answer*. Answers are for answering.

Comment: @Edlothiad, see my edit.

Comment: @AndresF, see my edit.

Comment: a list of examples is the definition of too broad.